# Any way to count data without using hierarchical foreach in blade view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I can count data using the below code.
I want to know any other way to count data without using this hierarchical foreach

=> $a , $b ,$c is table
=> fun1 & fun2 is one-many relationship of ( $a, $b )  &  ( $b, $c )

I try {{ $a->fun1->fun2->count() }} but it say  [fun2] does not exist on this collection instance

```
 $k=0;
 @foreach($a->fun1 as $b )
     @foreach($b->fun2 as $c)
         $k++;
     @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Comment: `$a->fun1->sum(function ($b) { return $b->fun2->count(); });`

Comment: thanx, bro. I find another way                                                        
         '@foreach($a->fun1 as $b ) <?php  $k= $b->fun2->count() +$k; ?>  
         @endforeach {{ $k }'                                                                                        
 but ithink your code is more simple than mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `$loop` variable

```
$loop->index
```

The index of the current loop iteration (starts at 0).

```
$loop->iteration
```

The current loop iteration (starts at 1).

```
$loop->count
```

The total number of items in the array being iterated.

```
$loop->parent
```

When in a nested loop, the parent's loop variable.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable